# Magento 2 API for product add to compare and compare list

Tags: product, api, rest-api, compare

There is any way to get API for product add to compare and get compare list for customer.
Thanks

Comment: Hello. Where u able to find rest API for add to compare?

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.magento.com/magedad-module-compareapi.html

This extension is useful for Add to compare API.